# Failed to load SWC binary for win32/x64

Tags: next.js

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bm05.png)
I also follow following step but it's still not working :
If SWC continues to fail to load you can opt-out by disabling swcMinify in your next.config.js or by adding a .babelrc to your project with the following content

Just help me out of this problem